# How do I delete a stucture without knowing its type?

Tags: c++, structure

This is the code that I have:

```
struct WndProcStatus {
    WNDPROC OrgWndProc;
};

struct ButtonWndProcStatus {
    WNDPROC OrgWndProc;
    bool bIsPressed;
    bool bIsFocused;
    bool bIsDefault;
    bool bIsDisabled;
    bool bDrawFocusRect;
    bool bMouseOver;
    bool bShowAccel;
};

struct EditBoxWndProcStatus {
    WNDPROC OrgWndProc;
    bool bIsFocused;
    bool bIsDisabled;
    bool bMouseOver;
    bool bTextSelected;
};
```

In my program, I will have a pointer to a ButtonWndProcStatus structure or EditBoxWndProcStatus structure, but I won't know which one it is.

Can I cast the pointer as WndProcStatus and then use the delete command to delete the structure from memory?

The pointers were created by using `LONG ptr = (LONG)new ButtonWndProcStatus()` or `LONG ptr = (LONG)new EditWndProcStatus()`.

Comment: Since all those classes have trivial destructors, you don't need to delete the object, and it suffices to free the memory allocated to it (i.e. by using `operator delete()` on the pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. It can only work if you use inheritance and if you give a virtual destructor to the structs/classes:

```
struct WndProcStatus
{
    virtual ~WndProcStatus() = default;

    WNDPROC OrgWndProc;
};

struct ButtonWndProcStatus
    : public WndProcStatus // derive, this also inherits OrgWndProc
{
    bool bIsPressed;
    bool bIsFocused;
    bool bIsDefault;
    bool bIsDisabled;
    bool bDrawFocusRect;
    bool bMouseOver;
    bool bShowAccel;
};
```

And now it should be safe to delete through a pointer. Also, you can easily write

```
WndProcStatus* p = new ButtonWndProcStatus; // look ma, no cast!
delete p; // this is now safe
```

Answer (score 1):

### No.

> *delete-expression*:   ::<sub>*opt*</sub>**delete** *cast-expression*
>
> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the
>   object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static
>   type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be
>   deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the
>   behavior is undefined [5.3.5 / 3]

The operand of `delete` should be as same as allocated type (unless base/derived situation)